# Android does not release memory on 4.4.2 samsung

Tags: java, android, memory-management, dalvik, samsung-mobile

new to android i'm starting to loose my hair :

When i launch my app on a Samsung this is what i get each time an activity launches :

```
 Pause GC
12-02 12:31:53.791: E/ActivityThread(10642): java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
12-02 12:31:53.791: E/ActivityThread(10642):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-02 12:31:53.791: E/ActivityThread(10642):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
12-02 12:31:53.791: E/ActivityThread(10642):    at android.app.ActivityThread.pauseGC(ActivityThread.java:5525)
12-02 12:31:53.791: E/ActivityThread(10642):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2324)
12-02 12:31:53.791: E/ActivityThread(10642):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2471)
12-02 12:31:53.791: E/ActivityThread(10642):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:175)
12-02 12:31:53.791: E/ActivityThread(10642):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1308)
12-02 12:31:53.791: E/ActivityThread(10642):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
12-02 12:31:53.791: E/ActivityThread(10642):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
12-02 12:31:53.791: E/ActivityThread(10642):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5602)
12-02 12:31:53.791: E/ActivityThread(10642):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-02 12:31:53.791: E/ActivityThread(10642):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
12-02 12:31:53.791: E/ActivityThread(10642):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
12-02 12:31:53.791: E/ActivityThread(10642):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
12-02 12:31:53.791: E/ActivityThread(10642):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-02 12:31:53.791: E/ActivityThread(10642): Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native method not found: dalvik.system.VMRuntime.pauseGc:(Ljava/lang/String;)I
12-02 12:31:53.791: E/ActivityThread(10642):    at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.pauseGc(Native Method)
12-02 12:31:53.791: E/ActivityThread(10642):    ... 15 more
```

This means (i think) the memory is not released so app crash when you use the app for a long time. 
I do not know what to say to my customer... 
Any help ? 
Thank you

Comment: Looks like an Android or vendor-specific bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bug on Samsung. Look [here](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=71073):

> Yeah, i don't think we ever had a VMRuntime.pauseGC method. (and even
>   if we did, VMRuntime and its methods are not public.)

And check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26615978/1991579) answer. Seems like this is Samsung bug.